# Interzoic Accord LMS API from VB.Net: how do you use it?

Tags: vb.net, api, dotnetnuke

Do I need to develop in the context of DotNetNuke source code?
Before calling

```
objLearningEventsList = objLMSClient.GetLearningEvents(intPortalId, intUserId,
  intManagerModuleId, intLearnerModuleId, intTabId, IgnoreConditions := True)
```

Do I need to connect the API to the database or use Interzoic's SqlDataProvider?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something that you are going to need to go to the developer of the API for specific information, as otherwise it is just a best guess.

However, based on the parameters listed, it appears to be focused on DNN data.

Answer (score 0):

The current API is just 'local' being intended for other DNN modules (running in the same site) using it.
Therefore, the idea is develop your own DNN module, using the LMS API to interact with it.
You do not access the database (regarding Accord stuff) directly. The API does this internally.

Note: A REST API will be developed soon. In this case, the 'client' app could be whatever: DNN or not, .NET or not, running in the same site or not.